# Good Windows emulators for gaming on Mac

Tags: windows, macos, emulator, gaming

A friend of mine wants to get a good Windows emulator so they have access to Windows features (such as the Microsoft store, etc.) They mainly want to be able to use games exclusive to Windows on their device. They are currently using a 2021 Mac Air with an M1 chip, so they can't use Apple's Bootcamp software.

The emulator does not necessarily need to be able to fake OSs besides Windows.

Some (must-have) requirements:

- Emulator is safe, and won't cause problems (must-have)
- Emulator can run intensive games at normal standards without noticeable impact (must-have)
- Emulator is not illegal or copyright infringing, or anything similar (must-have)

Some things that are preferred:

- Emulator is free (a one-time payment may be OK)
- Shouldn't require a lot of permissions to work, but may be OK sometimes (case-by-case basis)
- Emulator *should* be reputable or is made by a reputable company (again, case-by-case basis)

Please include multiple emulators in your answer so I can review multiple at once, in case one of them is shot down. Preferably 3+, but less is OK. Any emulators given as answers should fulfill all the requirements, but if you know one/some that could be good that miss some of them (that aren't must-haves), please give them as an answer (really trying to get as many options as possible).

Comment: "*Emulator can run intensive games at normal standards without noticeable impact (must-have)*" This is a pipe dream, if you can invent an emulator that doesn't have any performance impacts, you'll be a rich man. Even the best of emulators have only an "acceptable" performance penalty

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos What I meant was that you can still play intensive games at a quality somewhat resembling normal. By that, I mean that it should be playable, not (too) laggy (though no lag is obviously preferred), and it's somewhat expected that no major lags or fps dips would occur for too long a period of time (for an online competive game (15 seconds of lag or major fps dip is the max (also can't be too frequent))). A minor fps (frames per second, not first person shooter) dip would be acceptable, as long as it's not too damaging.

Comment: I'm not sure you can find any emulator that supports GPU virtualization on a MAC, most aren't even able to run applications that require graphics acceleration. Given that M1 is ARM architecture I don't think you will be able to virtualize the x86_64 architecture to begin with

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos The emulator wouldn't necessarily need to speed to speed anything up, it just needs to be able to run games at standards that are still enjoyable and not be too detrimental in online competitive games.

Comment: Honestly, tell your mate to get a machine with Windows. Or redirect them to WIne which is still the best gaming option there, albeit very limited.

Comment: @Destroy666 Is this Wine (https://www.winehq.org/)? Also, is it reputable and/or safe (that's a big sticking point)?

Comment: Yes. You'll find nothing that's more reputable. Just like I said, don't expect wonders. You'll be able to play a bunch of games, but far from all and the playable ones might be missing features or be buggy.